# invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using webdriver with javascript on Chrome and I get the the issue where iframe cannot be reached.

```
  get iFrame() {
    return $('.ul_iframe-background div iframe');
  }
```

```
  async positionToAuthForm() {
    const iframe = await this.iFrame;
    await iframe.waitForDisplayed();
    browser.switchToFrame(this.iFrame);
  }
```

I tried to use `browser.switchTo().frame(iframe)` but the error still exists